# Seperate attribute values with comma in xslt 1.0?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

My source XML:-

```
<wireframe:xaIDExclusion>
    <widget:xaID id="12"/>
    <widget:xaID id="121"/>
    <widget:xaID id="123"/>
    <widget:xaID id="124"/>
    <widget:xaID id="3456"/>
</wireframe:xaIDExclusion>
```

---

This is what i tried

```
<xsl:template match="widget:xaID">
      <xsl:element name="xaid">
<xsl:variable name ="value" select="@id"></xsl:variable>       
<xsl:value-of select="concat($value,',')"></xsl:value-of>
</xsl:element>        
</xsl:template>
```

---

I need output like this,how to do that

```
12,121,123,124,3456
```

---

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your namespaces prefixes are not bound. Please provide a well-formed input XML and a full XSLT stylesheet. Thanks!

Comment: I just need to know the logic,so i think the namespaces are not necessary

Comment: <xaid>12,121,123,124,3456</xaid>,i want to get my output inside this element,like in this pattern.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your approach is that you're matching `widget:xaID` and then creating a `xaid` element; this results in multiple `xaid` elements, one for each `widget:xaID`. You need to create the `xaid` element while you are in the context of the parent of `widget:xaID`.

Try (untested, because you did not provide a well-formed XML):

```
<xsl:template match="wireframe:xaIDExclusion">
    <xaid>
        <xsl:for-each select="widget:xaID">
            <xsl:value-of select="@id">
            <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">, </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xaid>        
</xsl:template>
```